# SSH find command not recognizing directory stored in local variable

Tags: ssh, find, variable

I'm able to SSH and go to the directory stored in a local variable `$out_dir`. However, I cannot figure out why the `find | head` command won't work. In **Try #2**, I added a second backslash at the end of the `find` command:

**Try #1 error:** `` find: `/dir/on/remote/server': No such file or directory ``

```
ssh $user@$ip << EOF
    discard=$( find $out_dir -exec basename {} \; | head -n -1 )
    for f in $discard; do
        echo "rm $f"
    done
    logout
EOF
```

**Try #2 error:** `` syntax error near unexpected token `|' ``

```
ssh $user@$ip << EOF
    discard=$( find $out_dir -exec basename {} \\; | head -n -1 )
    for f in $discard; do
        echo "rm $f"
    done
    logout
EOF
```

Comment: Not only will `$out_dir` be replaced by the local shell before `ssh` is called, but that whole command substitution will be performed locally. Likewise, the `$f` in `echo "rm $f"` and the `$discard` in the loop header will be expanded (probably to an empty string) before `ssh` is called.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using pssh? This would allow you to run the same command on multiple computers. I find it allows me to run scripts with simpler scripts & save time on debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the 'No such file or directory' in attempt #1 is that all variable and command interpolation for the heredoc (the `<<EOF`) is done locally, before it's being sent to the remote host.

As you correctly note, `$out_dir` is being interpolated; you see the directory you want to see.  This is happening on your local machine before you make the ssh call.  The command substitution (`$()`) is happening locally as well (but you intend to do this remotely).  Said differently, the entirety of the find is being processed locally before it is sent to the remote machine -- everything wrapped in `$()` is processed by the heredoc.  Thus, it seems `${out_dir}` isn't present on your local machine -- 'No such file or directory'.

If you'd like to see this better for yourself, let's pare down the example.  Try this:

```
$ ssh foo@localhost <<EOF
  echo "using account: $(whoami)"
EOF                            
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
<truncated>
using account: vagrant
```

Clearly the contents of $() are executing locally, as my local account is 'vagrant'; if working correctly, the account would have been 'foo' because I specified `ssh foo@localhost`.

Try #2 is broken because as you've escaped the '\' (rather than the ';').  Find needs the `-exec` terminated and now it is not.  Instead, the command ends abruptly, and you've a dangling ';' which terminates the bash command.  '|' expects to forward some input, but there's nothing specified.  Effectively, you created this:

```
$ | cat
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

So, what's a working solution?

Well, `find` can do the delete for you:

```
ssh $user@$ip <<EOF
  find $out_dir -delete
EOF
```

It's simple and direct.  If you're worried about picking some files, and excluding others, revise the `find`.

I give the 'revise the `find`' advice because in your current version, it looks like you're trying to do some edge case handling:

- the use of basename
- the use of `head -n -1`

But I don't expect this handling to work as you intend.

First, calling `basename` is going to strip most of the path, and in your ssh command, you're not doing anything to change directory.  Your ssh execution is going to try to delete everything relatively to ${user}'s home -- and in specifying ${out_dir} you seem to want to use a directory other than home!
Again, just let `find` do the deletes for you.

Second, and I may be off base with this one, but I suspect you use `head -n -1` to get rid of ${out_dir} from your list of target files.

```
$ find junk/
junk/
junk/one
junk/two
junk/three
```

Rightly, you don't want to delete `junk/`.

However, try this:

```
$ seq 1 4
1
2
3
4
$ seq 1 4 | head -n -1
1
2
3
```

This does not preserve the first line, it preserves the last.  Try tail:

```
$ seq 1 4 | tail -n +2
2
3
4
```

But again, just let `find` do the deletes for you.

If you need find to only remove files, look at `-type f`.  But there's also exclude and include patterns for more advanced filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ssh "$user@$ip" "out_dir=$out_dir;" '
    discard=$( find $out_dir -exec basename {} \; | head -n -1 )
    for f in $discard; do
        echo "rm $f"
    done
'
```

**Note:** the intended remote command could be made simpler and safer, but carping on that will only confuse the point.

Basically, you should pass the parts which **a)** should *also* be expanded on the *local* machine and those which **b)** should be *only* be expanded on the *remote* machine as *separate* arguments to ssh, the former double-quoted and the latter single-quoted.

Ssh will join all "command" arguments with spaces before passing them as a single argument to the `-c` option of user's login shell on the remote machine.

If the remote command should itself contain single quotes, you can use a command substitution + here doc combo. Also, if the value of the "local" variable can contain spaces and other special characters, you should escape them:

```
out_dir='/path/to/ * happiness * '
out_dir=$(printf %s "$out_dir" | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_/.]/\\&/g')
ssh localhost out_dir="$out_dir;" "$(cat <<'EOT'
  echo '<$out_dir>' = "<$out_dir>"
EOT
)"
```

Notice that single quotes in `<<'EOF'`; if omitted, the `$out_dir` in the here doc will be expanded (on the local machine).

Recent versions of bash have the `${var@Q}` form, so there you could simply use `"out_dir=${outdir@Q};"` instead of that ugly `echo | sed`.

Passing the remote script via stdin is rarely (if ever!) necessary.